# PyroCMS: autoload.php not finding customized helpers

Tags: codeigniter, pyrocms, pyro

I know this question has probably been asked a hundred times, but I'm trying to call a helper I made up from autoload.php. I stored the helper file in shared_addons/helper. I called it new_helpers. The helpers file is:

```
<?php defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed.');

public function get_date($timestamp, $format) {
  list($date,$time) = explode("|", date("m/d/y|g:i A", $timestamp));
  $date = date($format, $date);
  return $date;
}
public function get_time($timestamp, $format) {
  list($date,$time) = explode("|", date("m/d/y|g:i A", $timestamp));
  $time = date($format, $time);
  return $time;
}
```

and in system/cms/config/autoload.php, I put:

```
$autoload['helper'] = array('new_helper');
```

However, I am still getting the error:

An Error Was Encountered [ 500 ]

Unable to load the requested file: helpers/new_helper.php

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `I called it new_helpers` then load `new_helpers` instead of `new_helper`.

Comment: I meant I called the helper "new_helper." I edited my question.

Comment: You might get a parse error because of `public` keyword; remove the visibility keyword qnd try again.

Comment: What is interesting is that when I call "new_helpers" from the autoload file it calls "news_helper" instead.

Comment: It still happened even with "public" removed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The helper file name should follow the template `NAME_helper.php` If you want to name your helper "pdf", for example, the file name would be `pdf_helper.php`.

You would then use the name WITHOUT the _helper suffix for loading/autoload. So `$autoload['helper'] = 'pdf'`.

Comment: I tried this, too. I eventually decided to not autoload it, but instead just load it when I need it.

Comment: I tested this before I answered on version 2.1.3 and it worked fine. Whatever floats your boat, though.